# What do the numbers on the Users page mean?

Tags: support, users-page

For example, on this page: https://anime.stackexchange.com/users

I see the following:
[image: Number]

What does this **499** mean? I can't seem to correlate it with upvotes, posts, edits or anything else.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the answers. I did not notice the `week | month | quarter | year | all time` links near the search box. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the amount of reputation the user has earned in the period selected on the users page:

> week | month | quarter | year | all

The default is usually "week"

Answer (score 1):

It's reputation this month.  You can see the explanation in the status bar of your web browser if you hover over the number.

Answer (score 1):

It is the reputation for the period the page you are watching is referring: Your reputation increased of 499 in a month, and 170 in a week.